# Django Celery how to ignore task?

Tags: django, celery

I want to perform functional testing in Django.

How can I just ignore the Celery tasks during my tests ?

```python
class TestsFunctional(TestCase):

    def test_ignore_task(self):
        response = my_method()
        self.assertEqual(201, response)



def my_method():
    #just want to ignore tasks
    from celery import chain
    chain(tasks.long_task.s(), tasks.another_task.s()).apply_async()
    return 201


@task(default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=None)
def long_task():
    try:
        #infinite on localhost
    except socket.error:
        logger.warning("Service not reachable")
        long_task.retry()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
```

In my settings.py

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner'
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [Kevin Stone's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089197/kevin-stone) answer,  you can mock the Celery part of the test using the [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) decorator and [MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) like this:

**Test Code**

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

@patch('reference.to.your.long_task', new=MagicMock())
class TestsFunctional(TestCase):

  def test_ignore_task(self):
      response = my_method()
      self.assertEqual(201, response)
```

**Application Code**

```
def my_method():
  from celery import chain
  chain(tasks.long_task.s(), tasks.another_task.s()).apply_async()
  return 201

@task(default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=None)
def long_task():
  # Long running process
```

(YMMV)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a decorator that I add to functions that I want to skip during unit tests.

https://gist.github.com/kevinastone/7295567

You're other option would be to use `mock` and mock out the task.

Comment: thank @kevin-stone, I prefer mock my task and avoid to add coupling beetween my tests and my production code. It looks like a smell (separation of concerns).